# Best practice for searching on a remote server from iOS app

Tags: ios

There must be a better way to perform search on a remote server database than what I am doing right now.

I have a `UISearchController` installed on top of a table view that shows only 30 rows - Upon the user scrolling down to the bottom another 30 rows get loaded up and so forth...

So the the method I am using to perform the search looks like this:

```
func searchForWriter(searchString: String!) {
UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
Client.sharedInstance.searchForWriterByName(searchString) {(searchResults: [Writer]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
        NSLog("Error: %@", error.description)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        }
    } else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.filteredWriters = searchResults!

            // TODO: - This needs debugging to get the last searched string?
            print("searched for: \(searchString)")

            self.writersTableView.reloadData()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        }
    }
}
```

}

The `UISearchResultsUpdating` responds to any change in the `searchBar` and hence invoking the above `searchForWriter` method.

The problem is when the search results are obtained back from the server, there is no guarantee these will be for the last searched string?

In the matter of fact in almost most of the cases, this method will take longer time get results for a smaller search string rather a longer one... Hence giving completely frustrating search results

Comment: Rectify the search queries on your DB. And introduce paging to it (Which I guess you have done). Get lets say 20 contacts in first run. When you scroll down, get the next 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you ask several questions here:

1) What you are looking for concerning the amount of displayed rows is called **pagination**. Look it up for strategies how to do it, but in any case your server has to support it.

2) Concerning the search on each entered character: You should only start searching when at least n characters are entered (n being 3 or so), search results for only one character probably are useless anyway.

3) Add some timer constraint so that the search only starts when the user did not enter anything for 600 ms or so - this avoids lots of calls to the server for unnecessary intermediate results.

Comment: The client should also return something you can use to cancel the request

Comment: @TheEye - Thanks so much. Number 3 is exactly the solution I was looking for. I had already the results displayed 30 by 30 thru pagination. The search happens on the entire dataset, hence that was my question.

Comment: @Wain - I think this is even a better/ more practical solution! Just to make sure I got this correctly. The `Client` class should have a property like this `var taskToCancel: NSURLSessionDataTask? {didSet {if let taskToCancel = oldValue {taskToCancel.cancel()} } }`

Comment: It doesn't hurt to do that, too - but it's even better to not send requests that won't be needed instead of cancelling them in your code, as they will be sent to the server anyway, you just throw away the result.